# add handler to all controls of My component parent form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can i add handler to all controls of My component parent form when my component add to form , like tooltip component that add 'tooltips in tooltip1' property to all controls .
excuse me for my poor english

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the [IExtenderProvider interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx)

[See this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6c1xa43.aspx)